# How to update a field in an existing data extension using ampscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I am trying to add some random numbers to an existing data extension field. When I print the results in CloudPage, I get the results. But when I add a line to update data extension, it is hitting an error.

Please advise.

Here is the code I am using:

```
%%[
SET @count = RowCount(LookupOrderedRows("Filtered_Audience_New_Num",60000,"","Opted_In", 'True'))
FOR @i = 1 TO @count DO
 var @low, @high, @randomNum
 SET @low = 1000
 SET @high = 9999
 SET @randomNum = Random(@low,@high)
 UpdateDE("Filtered_Audience_New_Num",1,"Id",_SubscriberKey,"Key",@randomNum)
 OutputLine(Concat("Random Number ",@randomNum))
NEXT @i

]%%
```

Comment: How many rows in your DE?

Comment: Around 60000. The rows will increase or decrease, so used rowcount for exact row numbers.

Answer (score 1):

[UpdateDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/updatede.html) only works in an email send. In your case, you should use the [UpdateData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/updatedata.html) function as you need update rows in a Data Extension in a CloudPage. Otherwise your syntax looks OK.

**EDITED:**
This sounds like an X-Y problem to me, @DineshS. I would prefer using SQL for such bulk data operations. Especially since there is a limit of 2500 records, which SSJS can retrieve in one go. Also, there is already a unique number in each data extension, stored in a hidden `_CustomObjectKey` field (which you can query, and store in a standard Number field in destination DE). It is an auto-incrementing integer value on each data extension. Once you overwrite the data extension its records will have new `_CustomObjectKey` values.

If you start with 3 records. The `_CustomObjectKey` of those 3 records will be 1, 2, 3. Once you overwrite them with 5 new records, they will have values of 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 even though it looks like the data extension only has 5 records. Hence the last/highest value does not necessarily correspond to the number of records currently in that data extension.

Comment: I intend to use this code in an automation. Both, UpdateDE and UpdateData are not populating the filed. When used in script activity, I do not get any error.  The automation runs and completes.

Comment: You can't use Ampscript in a script activity. Only SSJS is supported.

Comment: SQL is the far preferred solution and can be easily automated as well. I would recommend following the Edit in this answer @DineshS

Comment: @DineshS - remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful